# Why an union wont allow its elements to have an user-defined constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unions, c++03

How can I make this second struct work, when the first struct has a constructor?
I get error:

```
error C2620: member 'test::teststruct::pos' of union 'test::teststruct::<unnamed-tag>' has user-defined constructor or non-trivial default constructor
```

The code:

```
struct xyz {
    Uint8 x, y, z, w;
    xyz(Uint8 x, Uint8 y, Uint8 z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
};
struct teststruct {
    union {
        Uint32 value;
        xyz pos; // error at this line.
    };
};
```

I could use a function to initialize the xyz struct, but wouldn't it be a lot slower? Not to mention: I have tons of structs I need to create own function with a prefix like init_xyz() or etc, which isn't nice. Is there any other way going around this problem?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, isnt there any other way going around this?

Comment: What are you using the unions for, are you trying to save memory?

Comment: @Rookie: Consider using the named-constructor idiom as a workaround for the naming conventions `struct xyz { static xyz init(int x, int y, int z); };`, as of performance, a constructor *is* a function, the same optimizations can take place including inlining, so there should be no performance differences.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, but why do i hear that i always should use initializer lists instead, because they are faster?

Comment: @ScottLangham, im not trying to save memory, but to simplify the data structures: i could repeat the struct 4 times, or i could just give more aliases for the variables. also im currently using the structs kind of type convertors: i can use 3 different types for one memory location, and when i use that memory, i choose the correct type such as data.int16_a, or data.int32, etc. I could cast that manually every time i use them, but i find the union very nice for that use.

Comment: @Rookie: That is a common statement, true. The validity of which needs to be discussed depending on the types. In particular for any object that you can use in an `union` in C++03 (i.e. POD), default initialization is a no-op, so the cost of assigning in the initialization list or outside of it will be the same. The cost differs if some of the members have default constructors, where the default constructor will be called (implicitly) in the initialization list just to reset the object through assignment.

Comment: Note that even if the initializer list actually set the `Uint8` (I am assuming that is a `unsigned char`) members to 0 (which it doesn't), the cost of that would be negligible

Comment: Ditch `xyz`'s constructor and use aggregate initialization instead. I.e., one would do `xyz var = {0,0,0};` instead of `xyz var(0,0,0);`.

Comment: @ildjarn, that is dangerous, what if i change the struct? i need to change the aggregate too. I did that mistake once, im not doing it again! **Edit:** and its not just xyz struct that im using, it was just simple example, as always.

Comment: @Rookie : Dangerous how? If you use aggregate initialization in any fashion, any members you omit will still be value-initialized (zero-initialized in the case of scalars); nothing will be uninitialized.

Comment: @ildjarn, `struct test {int x; int y; int z; }; test lol = {1,2,3};` then you go change struct to: `struct test {int x; int y; bool wtf; int z; };` and dont touch the `test lol = {1,2,3};` As i said... i already did this mistake once... every since i have avoided that method as much as possible. It *could* be OK for simple structs like XYZ... but anything else a big no. still, i would avoid it at most of the times... i do use it sometimes in array declarations though.

Comment: @Rookie : `test::wtf` is guaranteed to be initialized to `false` in that scenario. If it remained _uninitialized_ then I could see your point, but as it is, it is guaranteed by the standard to have a predictable, sensible value.

Comment: @ildjarn, how about z? anyways... even if that worked fine, i managed to not make it work fine once, and it was enough for me; took quite a long time to notice where the problem was.

Comment: @Rookie : Sorry, I misread/mistyped. In that scenario, `test::wtf` would be guaranteed to be initialized to `true` (and you're 99% likely to get a compiler warning about data truncation), and `z` is guaranteed to be initialized to `0`. The compiler warning makes this a poor example, but if you only add to the _end_ of your aggregate types (instead of to the middle) then you're generally safe. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn, i tested it now... and know what? no warnings when i do `test lol = {1,2};` even if there were million variables. thats probably how i made my error too: i added new variable there which wasnt initialized correctly; no warning telling me something is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably to avoid this:

```
struct A {
    Uint8 a;
    A() : a(111) {}
};

struct B {
    Uint8 b;
    B() : b(2222) {}
};

struct teststruct {
    union {
        A aValue;
        B bValue;
    };
};
```

What should happen, A and B constructors will both try to initialize the same memory in different ways. Instead of having some rule saying which will win, it was probably easier to say user defined constructors aren't allowed.

Comment: Yeah but... i dont have constructor which takes no parameters, so it shouldnt even try to initialize it, so i cant see a problem happening.

Comment: Yes, but C++03 basically works so that if you've got a class or struct that has a constructor, that constructor must be called to initialize an object of that class or struct type. You'd have to break that rule to make it work the way you'd like. Just because in your particular case it will work ok, it doesn't mean it should work that way. Similarly, you can drive perfectly well on the wrong side of the road if there's nobody coming the other way... but it's still useful to make it illegal to drive on the wrong side.

Answer (score 1):

From C++03, 9.5 Unions, pg 162

A union can have member functions (including constructors and destructors), but not virtual (10.3) functions. A union shall not have base classes. A union shall not be used as a base class.An object of a class with a non-trivial constructor (12.1), a non-trivial copy constructor (12.8), a non-trivial destructor (12.4), or a non-trivial copy assignment operator (13.5.3, 12.8) cannot be a member of a union, nor can an array of such objects